# Why !strcmp is used instead of strcmp?

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition

Here I wrote a code to find out whether a word is available or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *names[] = {"Sushant", "Jhon", "Robin", "Mark", NULL};
int search(char *p[], char *names);
int main(void){
    if(search(names, "Sushant") != -1){
        printf("Sushant is in this list");
    } else{
        printf("Sushant is not in this list.");
    }
    return 0;
}

int search(char *p[], char *name){
    register int t;
    for(t = 0; p[t]; t++){
        if(!strcmp(p[t], name)){
            return t;
        } else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine. But the problem is that. Why it is working? I am using `strcmp` to compare the array and given name but I am also using `!` at the beginning of `strcmp` to reverse the statement. The thing is that there should be only `strcmp` instead of `!strcmp` can you please tell me why `!strcmp` is used here?

Comment: [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns zero when the passed strings match.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the functions you're not sure about how they are working?

Comment: @klutt The documentation does not explain _why_ it, like many other functions, returns zero on equal.

Comment: @TrầnViệtHoàng Depends on what you mean. If you read what it does return, I find it's very easy to realize why it does not return zero or equal. Zero means equal, and if it's not equal, then the sign of the return value says something about HOW they are not equal.

Comment: @TrầnViệtHoàng  It is in the documentation.  According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp : `Return value: Negative value if lhs appears before rhs in lexicographical order, Zero if lhs and rhs compare equal, Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order.`So values other than 0 also have meanings and since numbers less than 0 mean the lhs is smaller and numbers greater than 0 mean the rhs is smaller it makes sense for equal to be in the middle.

Comment: It could instead be designed in different ways e.g. return 1 if lhs < rhs; return 2 if lhs == rhs; return 3 if lhs > rhs. This way users could avoid counter-intuitive test where `!strcmp` means equal. Does the documentation explain _why_ they chose zero?

Answer (score 3):

> Why !strcmp is used instead of strcmp?

It's a lousy idiom.  We can argue whether the poorness is the fault of the people using the idiom, or the people who designed `strcmp` the way it is, motivating the use of the (poor) idiom.

Some functions, of course, are "Boolean": they return a true/false value.  Others, like `getchar` and `sqrt`, are most definitely not: non-Boolean functions can return a whole range of values.  So the key question here is, is `strcmp` a Boolean function?  An important secondary question is, does `strcmp`'s name accurately reflect its Boolean or non-Boolean status?

`strcmp` is, of course, *not* Binary.  It can return 3 values: negative, zero, or positive, depending on whether the first string is lexicographically less than, equal to, or greater than the second one.  Moreover, as I just said, `strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings are *equal*.

Now, it's very common to want to write an `if()` statement that does something if two strings are equal.  And strings are second-class citizens in C, so you're not going to compare them with `==`, you're going to have to call a function.  So you're going to write something like

```
if(f(string1, string1))
```

So, if you *did* have available to you a string-comparison function that *did* return a Boolean, you could write something like

```
if(strings_are_equal(string1, string2))
```

Or, maybe, you could more or less equivalently write something like

```
if(!strings_are_different(string1, string2))
```

But you don't have a Boolean-valued string-comparison function, at least not in the Standard C library.  You have `strcmp`, which doesn't just tell you whether the strings are the same, it also tells you (if they're different) which one is greater.  That's supposed to be a help, but it ends up motivating the poor idiom you asked about.

Since `strcmp` returns 0 if the strings are equal, and since 0 is "false" in C, many programmers have discovered that you can write

```
if(!strcmp(string1, string2))
```

and it works.  As you'll notice, this is virtually the same code as the hypothetical

```
if(!strings_are_different(string1, string2))
```

I suggested earlier.  The only problem is that the name `strcmp` does not suggest difference; if anything it suggests similarity.  So unless you pay attention, it's easy to misread

```
if(!strcmp(string1, string2))
```

as saying, "do something if the strings are *not* the same", when in fact, what it's really saying is "do something if the two strings *are* the same".

Things might be better if `strcmp's` name were instead `strdiff`.  Then you could write

```
if(!strdiff(string1, string2))
```

and it would read well.  (There would be other problems, however: some programmers might write `if(strdiff(string1, string2) == TRUE)`, and wonder why it didn't work.)

What we're up against here is a point of programming style: the line

```
if(!strcmp(string1, string2))
```

might work properly, but it's confusing to read, and it might lead to mistakes later when someone carelessly maintains the program.

When you see the line

```
if(!strcmp(string1, string2))
```

one way to help to understand it is to mentally translate the name `strcmp` into `strdiff` or `strings_are_different`, and then you get the right interpretation of the `if` statement.

Me, in a program where I have lots of strings to compare, I write

```
#define Streq(s1, s2) (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0)
```

after which I can write

```
if(Streq(string1, string2))
```

and this way I get something that both works properly *and* reads well.

Comment: Wow, what an underrated answer. This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man strcmp`, strcmp returns 0 if the strings are identical. Since 0 represents false in a boolean context, we need the negation with `!strcmp` to check if two strings are equal.

---

**RETURN VALUES**
The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than 0, according as the string s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string s2.

Answer (score 1):

> Why !strcmp is used instead of strcmp?

It is because the author of the code is not very accurate.:)

The common used idiom is

```
if( strcmp(p[t], name) == 0 ){
```

Though these records

```
if( strcmp(p[t], name) == 0 ){
```

and

```
if(!strcmp(p[t], name)){
```

are equivalent nevertheless the first one is more clear,

The function `strcmp` returns 0 in case when two strings are identical.

From the C Standard (7.23.4 Comparison functions)

> 1 The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions
> memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the
> difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both
> interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
> compared

and (7.23.4.2 The strcmp function)

> 3 The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
> less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater
> than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

As for your code then it has a bug.

For starters there is no sense to declare the array `names` as global. It should be declared in main like

```
const char * names[] = {"Sushant", "Jhon", "Robin", "Mark", NULL};
```

As the function `search` does not change passed strings then it should be declared like

```
int search( const char *p[], const char *name );
```

The `else` statement within the function search shall be removed and the return statement

```
return -1;
```

must be placed after the for loop. For example

```
int search( const char *p[], const char *name )
{
    register int t;

    for(t = 0; p[t]; t++){
        if( strcmp( p[t], name ) == 0 ){
            return t;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I would define the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t search( const char *p[], const char *name )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( p[i] && strcmp( p[i], name ) != 0 ) ++i;
    
    return p[i] ? i : -1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char * names[] = {"Sushant", "Jhon", "Robin", "Mark", NULL};

    size_t i = search(names, "Sushant");
    
    if ( i != -1 ) puts( names[i] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given good answers, so I will not go in big details. Just for completeness I'll mention that it's because it can return three different values, because if the strings are not equal, then it will tell you which string that was "greater" with the sign of the return value.

And it would not make sense to return 1 on equal, because you would need two different "false" values.

**And the general answer to all C questions:** C is a very old language that predates most best practices today by decades. It's from 1971. Many of the best practices had not been discovered, and the language was designed for computers less powerful than most people can imagine today. Like the PDP-7 (that, in todays money value, would cost $670 000) that only had 9.2kB memory. It didn't even had a display. It had a printer instead. Corners were cut almost everywhere in early C. A goal with the language was to make it easy to write a very small compiler that could run on these systems. One priority was also to minimize the amount of characters needed to write code. Both because of memory, but also because of maximum line width on printers and early displays.

Don't use the `!` because that indicates it only returns true or false. Compare properly instead, like `strcmp(a,b) == 0` or `strcmp(a,b) != 0`. Utilize the sign of the return value if you have a need, which you might if you're writing a compare function for sorting.

If it bothers you, write this wrapper:

```
bool strEqual(const char *a, const char *b) {
    return strcmp(a,b) == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

But I would advice against it. One could argue that it's cleaner, but it's non-standard. If you want to learn C, then learn how other code C. I would not accept that function in a code review.